# How to adjust my TableView SectionIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a `UITableView` that utilises a header view at the top of the screen and an alphabetic sectionIndex bar at the top. My sectionIndex bar is transparent but it appears to extend the entire height of my tableView and cuts in to my header (see the white line in the top right corner).

How can I best remedy this?

[image]

Comment: does header view is that much important? you can replace it with custom view

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ I could but it would face the same issue unless there's a way to force a view to be in front of the section index right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In somewhere like viewDidLoad() in your tableviewcontroller, put the following lines and see if this works for you.

```
    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works, these properties are set to clear by default in Interface builder so I assumed they were clear but the constraints for the headerview had been affected. Thanks.